# More than an acquaintance, less than a friend?

Tags: vocabulary

Is there currently, in English, a word which describes the following kind of relationship:

A person who you know you could be close friends with (this feeling maybe even being mutual and/or outspoken) but who you never even become friends with due to, for instance, scheduling issues, distance, etc.

I'll also take colloquialisms, suggestions, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the difference is between a person who is an acquaintance and a person that you aren't good friends with but could be? I don't really see how the latter differs from the former.

Comment: An acquaintance is just "someone you know", and I feel that this does not do justice to the type of relationship I described above.

Comment: I suppose we have differing interpretations of the term acquaintance. I would say that you would need a closer social connection to someone than just knowing them to call them an acquaintance, though still less than a friend. I think the kind of relationship you're describing would still be an acquaintance, but of a differing degree (i.e. a distant acquaintance vs. a close acquaintance).

Comment: @talmey To me, an acquaintence is just "someone you know". Not saying I agree with the OP that we need a word to describe the state between just knowing someone and having befriended them, but I thought I'd put in my two cents.

Answer (score 2):

> Mate

In Australia this word does not mean precisely that, but is probably pretty close.

> He has a lot of mates and a few close friends.

Is "mate" more of a friend than acquaintance? I would say yes. You don't necessarily like an acquaintance, or even enjoy their company - but people who you are "mates" with are definitely people who you like to be around even if you are not that close, say work buddies. In fact, perhaps in an American context:

> Buddy

Comment: Eh. As an American, "buddy" just feels like another synonym for friend, like "chum". A person would need to clarify "well, we weren't close friends" for me to get that connotation. I could be the minority, though.

Comment: @ParthianShot Not being American I don't really know. In Australia, saying "just a mate" would indicate not a close friend. "Do you know him well?" - "Nah, he's just a mate". "Mate" is also appropriate to use directly to strangers, as in the classic "G'day mate" - but you would not describe a person as a "mate" to someone else unless you knew them a bit more and had something in common. To refer to someone you just met you would most likely say "that dude" or "some dude".

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking on this recently with a friend, and came up with "supraquaintance," to indicate a level above acquaintances but (implicitly) not yet at the level of friendship.

Comment: I was thinking "subfriend" would be better.

Comment: @HotLicks Well, I think the distinction just speaks to whether you're a "friend half empty" or "acquaintance half full" type person.

Comment: Would it not lead to less heartache and confusion if we just learned to classify our mutual closeness numerically? For instance: "I've always thought of you as a true XVII (2)(b), but now I realize that you're actually more of an XV (7)(g). No hard feelings, I hope?" Such a scheme would be simple, elegant, and straightforward to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not (ˈkĭndrəd) **[kindred souls](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kindred_soul)** ever meet or have time for each other is up to fate.

> (idiomatic) Someone with the same feelings or attitudes as oneself; **kindred spirit**.

Answer (score 1):

according to Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd...

ac•quaint•ance -- 1250–1300; Middle English < Old French]

syn:  acquaintance, associate, companion, friend refer to a person with whom one is in contact. An acquaintance is a person one knows, though not intimately: a casual acquaintance at school. An associate is a person who is often in one's company, usu. because of some work or pursuit in common: a business associate. A companion is a person who shares one's activities or fortunes; the term usu. suggests a familiar relationship: a traveling companion; a companion in despair. A friend is a person with whom one is on intimate terms and for whom one feels a warm affection: a trusted friend.